# Rails | Ruby | ArgumentError (Content-Length not given and Transfer-Encoding is not `chunked') on calling the list_contact_lists method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ses

Setting up the client

```
credentials = Aws::Credentials.new("AWS-SECRET", "AWS-KEY")
client = Aws::SESV2::Client.new(region: region, credentials: credentials)
```

I already have a contact list by name "Subscriber" ( This is from Aws console)

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-06-27-232 ~]$ aws sesv2 list-contacts  --contact-list-name Subscriber
{
    "Contacts": [
        {
            "EmailAddress": "abc@gmail.com",
            "TopicPreferences": [
                {
                    "TopicName": "Newsletter",
                    "SubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
                }
            ],
            "UnsubscribeAll": false,
            "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2023-04-27T07:03:29.024000+00:00"
        },
        {
            "EmailAddress": " abc2@gmail.com",
            "TopicPreferences": [
                {
                    "TopicName": "Newsletter",
                    "SubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
                }
            ],
            "UnsubscribeAll": false,
            "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2023-04-27T07:04:16.107000+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-06-27-232 ~]$
```

But when I try to call client.list_contacts

```
client.list_contacts(contact_list_name: "Subscriber",
                                filter: {
                                  filtered_status: "OPT_IN",
                                  topic_filter: {
                                    topic_name: "Newsletter",
                                    use_default_if_preference_unavailable: false,
                                  },
                                },
                                page_size: 1,
                              })
```

I am getting the below error

```
[Aws::SESV2::Client 0 0.861393 0 retries] list_contacts(contact_list_name:"ContactListName") ArgumentError Content-Length not given and Transfer-Encoding is not `chunked'

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):20
ArgumentError (Content-Length not given and Transfer-Encoding is not `chunked')
irb(main):022:0>
```

I also looked for a way to add the header explicitly but unable to do it.

I am trying to list the email contacts under **Subscribe** contact list from the **Newsletter** topic